# Which LINQ Query is quicker? Sort or select last?

Tags: performance, linq

I'm writing a LINQ query where I have to select the last result in a list.

Which is more efficient?

`.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).First();`

or

`.Last();`

Comment: That are apples and oranges. The first orders by Id, the second just takes the current order and picks the last. The latter is more efficient if it's already a collection like a list or array.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question asks what is faster, apples or oranges

Comment: Ok. That makes sense.

Comment: But you got my point? If the list was already ordered ascending by Id and you would use `Last` to get the item with the highest Id, then this would make sense. But of course something that is already ordered is faster than something that has to be ordered first, no matter if you use `First` or `Last`. If you compared `.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).First()` with `.OrderBy(x => x.Id).Last()` then `First` would be a bit more efficient since it doesn't need to enumerate all items.

Comment: I get what you mean. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither can be said to be more efficient. They do different things.

```
.Last();
```

This one returns the last element of a sequence (if there is one), without ordering

```
.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).First();
```

This one returns you the element that would be last if you'd order in ascending order, if there is one. It will give be the same result as:

```
.OrderBy(x => x.Id).Last();
```

```
var sequence = {4, 1, 3}
var a = sequence.Last();                        // result: 3
var b = sequence.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)   // intermediate result: 4, 3, 1
                .First();                       // final result: 4
var c = sequence.OrderBy(x => x.Id)             // intermediate result: 1, 3, 4
                .Last();                        // final result: 4
```

b is more efficient than c, because after ordering the enumerator only has to MoveNext to the first element, while for c the enumerator has to MoveNext(), until there are no more elements.